# Where can I discuss specific architecture/implementations I've created and get good feedback?

Tags: feedback

Let's say I've come up with what I think is a clean and elegant solution to a common generic requirement in coding projects. I'm happy to share my code but my main motivation for publishing it would be to get feedback from a quality audience about my solution and to determine if it has been done better elsewhere, if it could be done better, if it is buggy, etc. The normal sorts of reasons a programmer would want feedback for.

- [The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com) - ugly forum/comment interface and a serious pain when you want to update the article after it has been categorised. Can also be horribly slow at times.
- [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com) - not really a general code community; people would have to know what they're looking for in advance to find my code.

It would be fantastic if something like a simplified version of The Code Project were produced by the Stack Overflow team with a view to allow users to show off pieces of code and get feedback, thus leading to general skills improvement of everyone participating. A bit like Scott Hanselman's Weekly Source Code blog posts, but with more of a communal purpose. In the mean time, however, what do you suggest?

Comment: i rekkon you could put that stuff here. fair enuf, you may not be looking for an 'answer', but SO's interface seems a little better for the other requirements you spoke about than the alternative sites. ie. SO seems like the closest place to what you're after.

Comment: I suppose there's no harm in linking to external files. The problem of course would be that SO expects an accepted answer when the purpose would be more to get some discussion than to get a specific answer.

Comment: that was my point - you may not want an 'answer' but that's ok. i find heaps of SO questions that seem to never get 'answered' that are simply containers for discussions/ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It would be fantastic if something like a simplified version of The Code Project were produced by the Stack Overflow team with a view to allow users to show off pieces of code and get feedback, thus leading to general skills improvement of everyone participating.

There's now a sister Q&A website exactly for this purpose — [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was about to add it myself but saw you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could post your solutions here, as an answer to a question describing the problem that it proposes to solve.

You're likely to get at least a little feedback, and see other edits/version of a similar solution.